# SignalR server in winforms console with C# .net 7

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm new using SignalR and I'm trying to setup a server on a .net console that I will execute in a Win server 2012. I spend like 3 days on YouTube/Google etc but can't handle it when I execute the server in different pc's. In my pc I can connect client and server succesfully.

My goal is to get real-time updates with MS SQL, Entity-framework 7 and different clients in Winforms in net core 7, the server (does not care if is .net Framework or .net core).

I have this code in the server-side:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using serverPTP.Hubs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
class Program{
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
                {
                    EnvironmentName = Environments.Production
                });
    
                builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
                builder.Logging.AddConsole();
                builder.Services.AddSignalR();
    
                var app = builder.Build();
                app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:some port");
                app.MapHub<HubPTP>("/Hubs/HubPTP");
    
                app.UseHsts();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
    
                app.UseRouting();
    
                Console.WriteLine("3 seg for RUN:");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
    
                app.Run();
            
                Console.WriteLine("Continue..");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    
                if(ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }
            }
    
        }
}
```

If I run this app works, if I install this app in my pc works but in my windows server 2012 does not works. I have no errors messages, just inmediatelly after app.Run() closes the console...
**What is wrong in the code?**

I'm using the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 7.0.3

**UPDATE**

Now I also I'm trying to get it in Web enviorment.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins(new[] { "http://localhost:80", "https://localhost:80" })
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)); //for signalr cors  
});

builder.WebHost.CaptureStartupErrors(true);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});

// CORS Policies
//builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
//{
//    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
//}));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapHub<HubPTP>("/HubPTP", options =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Authorization data items: {options.AuthorizationData.Count}");
});


// Enable Cors
app.UseCors();

app.UseRouting();

app.Run();
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://172.28.8.2:80"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://172.168.8.2:80",
      "remoteDebugEnabled": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://172.28.8.2:8006/Hubs/HubPTP",
      "sslPort": 8006
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Server-side application log]

I'm unable to change the port, in Visual Studio I can change it and works fine if I launch the app but the port does not change if I install the App. It is always in port 5000 outside Visual Studio.

**EDIT- WORKING**
Finally after the @Blindy answer my signalr server works and I can connect to him from my own pc.

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.Urls.Add($"http://*:5000");
app.MapHub<HubPTP>("/Hubs/HubPTP");
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.Run();
```

With this method in my case didn't works: `app.UseHsts();` so I deleted this line.

Comment: Is there anything in the event log of your server?

Comment: @Marco I added the server info in web project. I tried to get it in console version but I didn't see errors.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you only trying to connect from the same computer where this thing is running, or are you trying to connect across computers?

Comment: @Blindy the server is in one pc with windows server 2012 and I'm trying to connect from my pc win 11. If I run both app from Visual studio works, but If I install it in my pc or windows server didn't work. And the port does not change like does in Visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the server is in one pc with windows server 2012 and I'm trying to connect from my pc win 11

Your start URI for the socket is wrong, `http://localhost:5000` means it will only bind to sockets *on your local machine*. That's why you see it on the launch screen, it's very important to set it correctly.

The URI you want is `http://*:5000`, or whatever port you want to use. This means that it will bind to *any* incoming socket.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the concept of `app.Urls.Add($"http://*:5000");`. Does this line mean that you can add different client IP to allow the connection to the server?

Comment: It's adding listening sockets with the usual socket API where you provide the IP address and port address to bind to. It has the exact same semantics, and if you want it to be accessible from the outside you have to create an `IPADDRESS_ANY` socket (or `*` in the ASP.Net Core language).

Comment: Also just in case you're confused about this, it's not what IP addresses are allowed, the point is to select an adapter to bind the socket to (or any adapter). It has nothing to do with actual IP addresses, they're just used against your routing table to get to an adapter.